# How do I loop over a struct slice in Go?

Tags: for-loop, struct, go, slice

I recently parsed a json message to a struct array like this:

```
type Fruit struct {
  Number string
  Type string
}

type Person struct {
  Pid string
  Fruits []Fruit
}

func main() {
  var p Person
  str := `{"pid":"123","fruits":[{"number":"10","type":"apple"},{"number":"50","type":"cherry"}]}`
  json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &p)

  //loop struct array and insert into database
  stmt, err := tx.Prepare(`insert into empi_credentials(PID, type, num) values(?, ?, ?)`)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
  }
  defer stmt.Close()

  for x := range p.Fruits {
    if _, err = stmt4.Exec(string(i), x.Type, x.Number); err != nil {
      log.Println("stmt1.Exec: ", err.Error())
      return
    }
  }
}
```

When I compile it, the compiler says x.Type and x.Number undefined...

How can I fix it?

Comment: When ranging over a slice the first value is the index and the second value is the element at that index.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To fix errors

```
undefined: i
x.Type undefined (type int has no field or method Type)
x.Number undefined (type int has no field or method Number)
```

change

```
for x := range p.Fruits
```

to

```
for i, x := range p.Fruits
```

Reference: [For statements](http://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements)

Comment: Thanks very much~ I'm a new Gopher and I think I must read the Docs in detail

Comment: And if you don't use i,may be `for _, x := range p.Fruits` better